# Copy and Pasting one Cell at a time from a List

Tags: browser, copy-paste

Is there a way to copy and paste a list from a spreadsheet and then paste into a browser one at a time.

For example: Let's say we have a column in google sheets (or excel) that is as follows:

ASDE1
ASDE2
AZED1
AZED2
AZED3
BEES5

Is there a way to copy this list and have the output be ASDE1 by itself followed by ASDE2 by itself and so on.

I basically need to show that each of these strings individually can be found on a webpage.

I do a lot of validating code in the backend of our support site and it's a pain to copy and paste one at a time.

Comment: "and have the output be .. by itself " do you mean pasting it at the address bar?

Comment: Explicitly, I am using the find tool on a page to make sure the content of each cell in a list can be found on a webpage.

Comment: perhaps this [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=search+multiple+terms+in+a+page) & its [results](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-browser-extensions-for-searching-multiple-words-on-a-webpage-chrome-firefox/) may helps.